# Babel does not recognize `export Component from './Component'`

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I have installed `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from`, but for some reason, my default export is not being transformed. Typescript keeps throwing the error,

```
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from (https://git.io/vb4yH) to
    the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

I've taken a look at [this](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7293) issue and have tried installing `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from` as well, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing something?

My `babel.config.json`:

```
{
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from", "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from"]
}
```

[image: romantic-kirch-fzmvy]

FWIW, I haven't ejected out of my CRA app, and I'm wondering if I need to do so, or use something like rewired, in order to use this in my project.

Comment: It should be easier if you can share a demo of your simplified project.

Comment: I've shared a Codesandbox. The behavior is the same as in my project.

Comment: Can you not do the following?
`import Component from "./Component";`
`export default Component;`

Comment: I can, but I want to try this babel plugin instead

Answer (score 2):

By default, `create-react-app` hides webpack, babel configurations and preconfigured.
Which means if you build your project directly, the babel.config.json doesn't work.
So you need to run `npm run eject` to customize the configuration.
By the way, you may also need to upgrade `react-scripts` to `4.0.1` to do `npm run eject`. Once you done this, then your babel configuration works, and I think you shouldn't see the error your met. But I didn't try to find the reason of another error when I checked your demo.